# Is it possible to combine Site.com with Force.com sites

Tags: force.com-sites, site.com

I wonder is it possible to combine functionalities of both Force.com sites and Site.com pages. I know that I cannot use Visualforce pages / Apex code in Site.com, but is it possible to add reference from site.com site to Force.com site (for example I would like to add Force.com site as a menu option in Site.com site's menu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not combine Force.com sites and Site.com together on a single page. Both have different structure. Site.com is like static page having some dynamic widgets to perform basic operations. You can navigate from site.com page to Force.com site visulaforce page but cannot mix them together.

Non-recommended workaround is select the Salesforce Tabs + Visualforce Template. Hack its CSS to hide the native header and inject the site.com header using javascript abnd CSS.

Comment: Site.com does not allow you to use Visualforce and apex . site.com supports HTML,CSS,Javascript and also there are special elements called repeaters and there are content blocks where you can pull data from objects on the block. As a workaround you can show Force.com site in an iFrame present in site.com. And communicate via cross domain javascript with Porthole JS library.

Comment: Will I be able to somehow authenticate on Force.com site? Right now I can see only data exposed to public profile.   I would like to get user that is logged on site.com page and run visualforce page(with controller) in his context.

Comment: Try using Ajax toolkit. @KamilGrzywacz